Transfer from cloudflare worker to vercel
I want to move the following code that works in Cloudflare Worker to another server like Vercel
worker.js
addEventListener(
    "fetch", event => {
        let url = new URL(event.request.url);
        url.hostname = "popdev.me";
        url.protocol = "https";
        let request = new Request(url, event.request);
        event.respondWith(
            fetch(request)
        );
    }
);

I tested it in the repository below as I thought it was correct, but it didn't work
https://github.com/fx505/nodejs-serverless-function-express
Please guide me what changes to make and how to set it up
